# I am making an iOS app that take a panoramic picture on its own

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

iPhone can be stood on the ground and then, when it vibrates, it spins on the ground
so we can use this feature to take a panoramic picture.
actually there is an app that functions the same I wrote above. The app is called "Cycloramic"
It could be meaningless, but I want to build this app to study iOS programming.

Now I faced a problem, that it just vibrates, ignores a part of taking pictures.

this is the code.

when I pushed the button, it starts.

first, it takes a picture then vibrates until it rotates 29 angle. Then it takes one more picture.
This is what it is meant to function.

But, when I start the app, it only vibrates and never takes a picture at all.

what is wrong with it?

```
if([self.rangeSelectionButton.title isEqualToString:@"90"])
{
    range = 90;
}
else if ([self.rangeSelectionButton.title isEqualToString:@"180"])
{
    range = 180;
}
else if ([self.rangeSelectionButton.title isEqualToString:@"270"])
{
    range = 270;
}
else if ([self.rangeSelectionButton.title isEqualToString:@"360"])
{
    range = 360;
}
else
{
    return;
}


switch (range)
{
    case 90:
        [self.imagePickerController takePicture];
        [self.motionSensor updateGyro];
        self.beforeRoll = self.motionSensor.roll;

        for(;(self.motionSensor.roll - self.beforeRoll) <= 29;){
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
            [self.motionSensor updateGyro];
        }

        [self.imagePickerController takePicture];

        [self.cameraTimer fire];
        break;
    case 180:

        break;
    case 270:

        break;
    case 360:

        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

I posted entire code above.
The if statements check the angle I want to take a pictures.

The switch statements functions, according to angle. I was writing only 90 angle part.
Thanks.

Comment: Post the code related to taking the picture (the bit that doesn't work).

Comment: trojanfoe, I added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImagePickerController/takePicture) for `takePicture`:

> Calling this method while an image is being captured has no effect.
>   You must wait until the associated delegate object receives an
>   [`imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController%3adidFinishPickingMediaWithInfo%3a) message before
>   you can capture another picture.

Are you making sure that the original image has been captured?

I don't think that `UIImagePickerController` is the right library to use for what you are trying to do.. It would probably be a better idea to use [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html) to get the pictures you want.

Apple have also provided the sample project [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) to show how you can achieve this.